# Need some help regarding Destination Tag

Tags: node.js

Good day hope this txt find you well guys i would like to have more explanation regarding the destination Tag on XRPL

Is it possible that a same wallet address can have many destination Tag to credit clients

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an account can have multiple destination tags.
Usually exchanges track the user's funds via Destination Tags in their backend.

The XRP Ledger can NOT distinguish funds based on Destination Tags. This has to be done in YOUR backend.

So lets say you have a backend with multiple users. Each user has its own Destination Tag. The users can send funds to your account and attach their personal Destination Tag to the transaction.

Now you can match the incoming transaction on your account via the Destination Tag with the user.

So the Destination Tag is the identifier for you to match the correct user.

This is how most Exchanges handle their funds on the XRPL.

See also: https://xrpl.org/source-and-destination-tags.html

Comment: Thanks for this answer have added more in my research i would like to ask more about this !!! is it possible to make a "Transaction" from an account on the same account but indicating the destination tag to refer to a payment on my backend system...

Comment: If both Account and Destination are same in a transaction, then it fails with following error code: temREDUNDANT. 

But there is a easy solution for this problem which I've explained here:
https://learn.xumm.dev/xrpl/source-and-destination-tags